# Google storage (curl + PHP + create a dummy _$folder$)

Tags: php, storage, google-apps

Can anyone enlighten me how to create a _$folder$ using Google storage API? Here is the class that I have so far (I managed to list/filter files), but no success with creating a 'directory'. http://guy.codepad.org/lEO4J6hL

When I try to create a test_$folder$, this is what I send to the server:

```
PUT /test_$folder$ HTTP/1.1
Host: static.hotelpublisher.com.commondatastorage.googleapis.com
Date: Mon, 29 Nov  2010 19:45:49 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-MD5: 1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
Authorization: GOOG1 GOOGRVMFQJPKHRXAU3F6:gtzlxexMjBOafn5tOZKF7UZGv1I=
x-goog-acl: public-read
```

This is what I get in return:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>MalformedHeaderValue</Code><Message>An HTTP header value was malformed.</Message><Date>mon, 29 nov  2010 19:34:23</Date></Error>
```

This is done following the Google provided documentation, thus I don't see why this does not work.

Comment: I am still struggling how to create a _$folder$ using Google Storage API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... have you tried taking out the Content-MD5 header? It doesn't look like it's necessary since your Content-Length is 0.

Comment: I think it is time to report a bug.

Comment: Hm... the Date header also looks like it's got an extra space between the month and the year. Glancing at your php code, the format looks fine, though glancing at your php code, it also looks like it does a POST rather than a PUT, which weakens my confidence that that's the latest version. You might try calling gmdate(DATE_RFC1123), to minimize errors in your format string.

Comment: gmdate(DATE_RFC1123) actually worked! I can't understand how it is different from gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') [the output seem to be the same?] but it did work.